# equality of subobjects

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

Suppose A $\xrightarrow{f}$ B $\xrightarrow{g}$ C is exact in an abelian category. f and g has factorization f = me and g = m'e' where m and m' are monic and e and e' are epic. Then e = m' as subobjects.

I cannot see how e = m'. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How does an epimorphism $e$ define a subobject?

Comment: thank you for the comment! I feel it a bit off because epimorphisms should define quotient objects... My question is from P309 of Rotman's Intro to Homological Algebra. Thx!

Comment: Intuitively $e$ is an isomorphism $A\to A'$ for some object $A'$ and $m'$ is an isomorphism $C' \to C$ for some object $C'$, so they should both define subobjects (I am a bit rusty with the axioms, but from memory I think the proofs of these statements are standard).  As to why they are the same object, it seems like you need more information, or perhaps a weaker definition of 'same'.

Comment: What Rotman writes makes no sense. He writes the equality $[e]=[m']$, but by definition these are equivalence classes for different relations on different classes. It must be a mistake.

Comment: It seems like the right thing to say would be that $m$ and $\ker e'$ give the same subobject.